# session lost after refresh in a some PC browser Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm setting up a web site using codeigniter and i'm having a problem : the session is lost after a redirection and after refresh. It's working fine in some device that i tested (4 devices : linux and windows) and it's not working on others especially on the server that will contain the website. I've tried to save the session in the database and in a file but it's not working.

My Config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

My controller

```
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->user_id = isset($this->session->get_userdata()['user_details'][0]->id)?$this->session->get_userdata()['user_details'][0]->users_id:'1';
    var_dump($_SESSION['user_details');
}

/**
  * This function is redirect to users profile page
  * @return Void
  */
public function index() {
    if(is_login()){
        redirect( base_url().'user/profile', 'refresh');
    } 
}

/**
  * This function is used to load login view page
  * @return Void
  */
public function login(){
    var_dump($_SESSION['user_details');
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_details'])){

        redirect( base_url().'user/profile', 'refresh');
    }   
    $this->load->view('include/script');
    $this->load->view('login'); 
}
```

Comment: which CI and PHP versions are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using CI 3.0.6 and  PHP 7.3.7

Comment: try to update to latest CI. also get_userdata() is legacy method use this->session->your_session_key and check the typo you have in line of get_userdata()[; check: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem was solved by dowgrading the php version or by using the last version of CI.